# request.getSession() vs getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()

Tags: java, session, servlets, thread-local

What is the difference between

```
request.getSession()
```

and

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
```

The application I am maintaining appears to use the first for straight Servletsand the second for anything implemented via GWT-RPC which itself extends servlet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both return the same thing. GWT simply stores the request sent in from the servlet into a thread local so that you don't need to pass it around in every method call and still have a separate `request` for each invocation.

Comment: Where does `request` come from? I'm coding in JSP at the moment and trying to figure out how I get access to it. (I'm completely new to this.)

Comment: JSPs automatically have access to the `request` variable, you should be able to do something like `<%= request. getRequestURL() %>` right off the bat.

Comment: Abdullah Jibaly, that worked! Thank you! Now, how do I access request from the .java class files that my JSP file calls? EDIT: I could pass in the result. I need access to `request.getSession(true)`. But is there a better way for the Java method to have access to it?

Comment: If it's just a plain Java class (not a servlet) then the only way to get the session is to pass it in.

Comment: Ok, so ultimately it just always exists, if it's a servlet? It's not created by the code, it's created by the session itself? (Bad wording perhaps.)

Comment: Well a servlet is passed in the request (from the servlet container) so it can use that to get the session. From that perspective it's the same as any normal Java class.

Answer (score 4):

[getThreadLocalRequest()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html#getThreadLocalRequest%28%29)  is convenience method to get the HttpServletRequest.

Both request.getSession() and getThreadLocalRequest().getSession() returns the same HttpSession the difference is the way you obtain the HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that you use your own RPC methods in your GWT Servlet which do not get the `HTTPRequest` as a parameter - in contrast to the standard Servlet methods `doGet(...)`, ..., `doXYZ(...)`. Thus, the only way to access the `HTTPRequest` is the provided `getThreadLocalRequest()` of GWT's `RemoteServiceServlet` which you should normally extend.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is scope. Specifically, request variable is only available directly from the `doGet(..)`, `doPost(..)`, etc. methods scopes (inside the methods). Once the thread you are in exits the method and enters your biz method `doSomething()`, etc., your code has no access to the request variable anymore (scope changed), but `getThreadLocal..()` allows you to gain the access regardless of the method you are in, given of course you are in the same thread as the `doGet()`, etc.